# Having trouble in updating phpMyAdmin(XAMPP) database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

I am new to php, I am learning how to update table using php with help of sql queries. But somehow, I have got stuck at the SQL query part. It always shows an error that I cant understand.

The query which I use is : `$query= "UPDATE users SET username = '$username' , password = '$password'  WHERE id = $id " ;`

And the **error** that I get is :

> *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1*

At first I was looking for any syntactical errors but I guess that's not the case..

I am also mentioning the validation isset code that I have been using just in case.

```
<?php
include "db.php"; 
include "functions.php"; 
?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $username= $_POST["username"];
    $password= $_POST["password"];
    $id= $_POST["id"];

    $query= "UPDATE users SET username = '$username' , password = '$password'  WHERE id = $id " ;

    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(!$result){
        die("QUERY FAILED".mysqli_error($connection));  
    }

}
?>
```

`$connection` has already been defined at db.php..

Can you please tell where my fault is ??

Comment: looks like one or all values inside your query is empty.

Comment: is your database field name is correct ?

Comment: Can you show your database table name and field name?

Comment: I have 3 columns in my database - id,username, password and my table name is : "users"

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting **id,username and password** values then

Just Try this

```
$query= "UPDATE `users` SET `username` = '$username' , `password` = '$password'  WHERE `id` = $id " ;
```

Comment: try to echo $username , $password, $id . Are you getting values? or is it blank?

Comment: getting values for username , password, id is set for auto incremental in the phpMyAdmin..

Comment: <?php
   
// to connect with the database..

   $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ' ', 'loginapp');  
    if(!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed");
    }

?>

Comment: After your $query line add `echo $query; exit;` Display the query and share it

Answer (score 0):

Are your passwords hashed in your database?  If so, that could be your problem. Try this.

```
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost => 12'));

$query= "UPDATE `users` SET `username` = '$username' , `password` = 
'$hashed_password'  WHERE `id` = $id " ;
```

If you are storing your password in your database as plain text, I would recommend using this password_hash function.  I would also recommend checking out prepared statements for this as well as it is more secure and will help to protect against sql injection.